# Java2D OpenGL Hardware Acceleration Doesn't Work

Tags: java, opengl, hardware, hardware-acceleration

It doesn't work with OpenGL with even the simplest of programs. Here is what I am doing.

```
java -Dsun.java2d.opengl=True -jar Java2Demo.jar
```

(`Java2Demo.jar` is usually included with the JDK.)

The text output is:

> OpenGL pipeline enabled for default config on screen 0

When I don't pass in the above VM argument things work fine (but slowly). When I do pass in the above argument nothing shows up. If I move the window around it captures whatever image it was on top of and jumbles it into nonsense.

I'm running Windows XP Pro SP3 (Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]) (under Parallels on OS X 10.5.8).

I used "Geeks3D GPU Caps Viewer" to tell me I have Open GL version:

> 2.0 NVIDIA-1.5.48

I have tried this with two version of the JVM. First:

```
java version "1.6.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_13-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.3-b02, mixed mode)
```

and second:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7, [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) 3.1.8: With `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true`, I see better frame rates, but the result is choppy. Without the option, I see smooth results with frame rates about 50% of the native (Mac OS X) pipeline. The result hinges critically on installing the [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) host additions for graphics; you might check for a similar feature in Parallels.

Comment: As far as I can tell there are no special additions to Parallels. There is "Parallels Tools" which installs automatically by default and installs various drivers to let Windows use the Mac hardware. This is already installed for me however and apparently without it installed getting a resolution over 640x480 may not be possible, for example..

Comment: Just something to check and something I've occasionally forgotten. Both VirtualBox and (I'm told) Parallels require updating their additions/tools when updating the base product.